# Google Cloud Messaging Unknown source exception

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hello I want to implement Google's GCM into my android application.

I linked to google play services lib

I wrote the following permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.torasecurity.mobile.alarm.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


<permission android:name="com.torasecurity.mobile.alarm.C2D_MESSAGE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.torasecurity.mobile.alarm.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

A simple broadcast receiver:

```
  <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" android:exported="true"
       android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME" />
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

But I get this stack trace when trying to register:

```
08-07 11:43:12.806: W/System.err(19067): java.io.IOException: MAIN_THREAD
08-07 11:43:12.826: W/System.err(19067):    at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
08-07 11:43:12.826: W/System.err(19067):    at com.torasecurity.mobile.alarm.SplashScreen.register(SplashScreen.java:27)
08-07 11:43:12.826: W/System.err(19067):    at com.torasecurity.mobile.alarm.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:56)
08-07 11:43:12.826: W/System.err(19067):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
08-07 11:43:12.826: W/System.err(19067):    at
```

Does any body know what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most probably you are trying to register to GCM directly from the activity.
But the `register()` method accesses the network, and like any other method that performs network operations, it should run in a separate thread otherwise an exception is thrown.

The solution is to put the registration to GCM in a thread, for example in a `AsyncTask`, like in [docs.](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) (`registerBackground()` method).

Comment: the register method is now deprecated.